# How to return a Thenable CompletionList

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, monaco-editor

I'm trying to improve performance of a monico editor completion item provider (it is currently making ajax calls to get the appropriate items ... the custom language is very large and complex).

I'm wonderingf if/how returning a Thenable CompletionList might help with this. 
https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/api/interfaces/monaco.languages.completionitemprovider.html

We initially started with a synchronous ajax call so that we are sure to have results to present, but that was causing too much blocking/interruption in typing flow. Now the ajax call is asynch but is not returning fast enough and we get a 'No suggestions' message.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. In case anyone else is wondering how to do the same. From the provideCompletionItems function ...

```
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'someaddress.com',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
      // create your keywords json here
      resolve({items: keywords, isIncomplete: true});
    },
    error: function(xhr, error){
      reject({items: [], isIncomplete: true})
    },
  });
});
```

The monaco editor will then display a nice little set of animated dots as a loading indicator while the ajax call happens.

Comment: Thanks very much and I wonder if it's possible to make multiple ajax calls within one promise? In my problem there could be more than one source for a completion.